# Activerecord-reputation-system - how to check value of current_user's vote

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm checking if a user has voted on a given post and then changing the up and down arrows' styling. The `activerecord-reputation-system` gem hasn't been updated in a while and every example I find either uses outdated code or requires tracking "up" votes and "down" votes separately. I prefer to just use `:post_votes` and check the value of that one parameter.

posts_controller.rb

```
@voted_items = Post.evaluated_by(:post_votes, current_user)
```

index.html.erb

```
<% if current_user && @voted_items.include?(post) %>
  # display active up or down arrows
<% end %>
```

How do I get just the value of the relevant record within the `@voted_items` object?

**Edit**: I notice there is no built-in scope for :value. Maybe adding one manually would let me query a particular value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I am came up with this method def on the model:

```
def evaluation_value(user, comment)
  if @up_voted = ReputationSystem::Evaluation.where(:reputation_name => "comment_votes", 
      :value => "1.0", :source_id => user.id, :source_type => user.class.name,
      :target_id => comment.id, :target_type => comment.class.name).exists?
    "upvoted"
  elsif @down_voted = ReputationSystem::Evaluation.where(:reputation_name => "comment_votes", 
      :value => "-1.0", :source_id => user.id, :source_type => user.class.name,
      :target_id => comment.id, :target_type => comment.class.name).exists?
    "downvoted"
  else
    nil
  end
end
```

It's not ideal because it requires hardcoding the values and other details, but it works for now until the gem is updated to allow checking individual values.

This way I can run `comment.evaluation_for(current_user, comment) == "upvoted"` or downvoted.